# Can compile an .exe from other .exe? .NET

Tags: c#, .net

if a .exe is made with c# and .net framework, can compile other solution,  creating an .exe with a determinated code ?, it its possible ?, if yes, should the client have visual studio or something ? 
How can i make an .exe with a determinated .dll from another .exe made with .net ?

Comment: What you're describing fits more dll than and exe. So if you create a class library project and compile it to a dll, you can then include that dll in another project which compiles to an exe.

Comment: but i cant compile an .exe without and ide like vs ?

Comment: You can, you only need the compiler and you can compile your project from the command line.

Comment: so if the user have visual studio with .net framework, an .exe could genereate another one ? with determinated c# code ?

Comment: Yes; your own process can run the C# compiler; or even msbuild (this is how CI systems work)

Comment: okey so its possible to create an .exe from a exe with dlls, that later u could use without dlls right ?

Answer (score 0):

Everything .NET Compiels into MSIL. It shares some similarities to JavaBytecode in function.

Every MSIL language can use any existing MSIL compilation. Indeed large parts of the .NET Framework itself are in MSIL format. Normally such code is provided as .dll. It is a convention established in decades of programming.

However internally there is little difference between a MSIL .exe and .dll. The only differences that come to mind is a bit of Native Copiled Code to bootstrap the whole thing. And a manifest that says "this class has the main function". There might be some minor differences (like supported COM interop), but those usually do not mater.

Note that this behavior is rare. Only MSIL and JavaBytecode have this property (.executeables are just .dll's with some extra start code/information).

As a result you can use any MSIL .exe like you would a MSIL .dll. Just add it to the Project references, maybe add a using. And go on programming.